# Need help in better chart visualization (mpandroidchart)

Tags: android, realm, mpandroidchart

This is my code for displaying bar chart from realm database. StartDate and EndDate are having Date datatype. Query result is perfect but its display on chart is not as expected. Please take a look.Find image here. [HERE is the chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tlRmo.jpg) .

**RealmResults results = realm.where(Transactions.class).between("mydate",StartDate,EndDate).findAll();
        RealmBarDataSet barDataSet = new RealmBarDataSet(results,"Sales_order","id");
        barDataSet.setColors(new int[]{ColorTemplate.rgb("#FF5722"), ColorTemplate.rgb("#03A9F4")});
        barDataSet.setLabel("Realm BarDataSet");**

```
    ArrayList<IBarDataSet> barDataSets = new ArrayList<IBarDataSet>();
    barDataSets.add(barDataSet);
    RealmBarData Data = new RealmBarData(results,"date", barDataSets);
```

In RealmBarData() ,"date" is string and I cannot use mydate(Date datatype) cause it will raise **IllegalArgumentException:Column type Invalid**

```
chart.setData(Data);
    chart.animateY(1400, Easing.EasingOption.EaseInOutQuart);
    chart.notifyDataSetChanged();
chart.invalidate();
```

So please help,if you have any idea how to display it as usual or any other corrections in code.

Comment: I don't understand the question. Cannot you just convert the `String` to `Date` when you save it to `RealmBarData`?

Comment: I cannot put Date argument in RealmBarData() constructor,it will raise Exception as mentioned above in my question.

Comment: Can you please share the code of `RealmBarData` in the question?